# Jquery toggle show and hide text change

Tags: jquery, toggle

I've been hunting for awhile now and I just can't find an answer or get this to work as I want.

Right now I have some content which is hidden, then expands down when clicked on "Read More" But when its been clicked, I would like that text to be changed to "Less" or "Hide" or something.

Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.moreinfo').hide();
    $('.more').click(function () {
        $('#info'+$(this).attr('target')).toggle(500);
        return false;
    });  
});
```

Then that goes to this html

```
<p class="moreinfo" id="info1">CONTENT HERE</p>
<a class="more" target="1">Read More</a>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use callbacks here **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eb5C5/)**

```
        $('.moreinfo').hide();
        $('.more').click(function (ev) {
           var t = ev.target
           $('#info' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle(500, function(){
              $(t).html($(this).is(':visible')? 'I\'m done reading more' : 'Read more')
           });
           return false;
        });
```

You can read more about [jQuery.toggle(), here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much, I have to wait 9 minutes aparently to accept your answer but I will make sure I do. Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious why you use single quotes and escape apostrophes with a backslash rather than using double quotes. Either way this was the solution I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#div1").click(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'More' ? 'Less' : 'More'); 
    $("#div2").slideToggle("slow");

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function slidtogl_contnt(id1){
    $("#"+id1).slideToggle();
    var txt = $("#more_txt").text();
    if(txt == 'More....'){
      $("#more_txt").text('Less....');
    }
    else{
      $("#more_txt").text('More....');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Atif. Please consider adding some explanations to your answer... ;)

Comment: This question was asked 4 years ago, and was resolved.